# Aurelia @children with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, parent-child, aurelia

Suppose I have a custom element in which I iterate over an array of data and render custom subelements.

```
<my-list action-handler.bind="actionHandler">
  <my-element item.bind="element" repeat.for="element of data"></my-element>
</my-list>
```

In `my-list.html` I render the contents with `<contents></contents>` and in general the real code is a bit more complex and has replaceable template parts, but that's not the problem.

I want the `actionHandler` that I bind to `MyList` to be available in all of the children. For the sake of elegancy, we did this in `my-list.js`:

```
@children('*:not(div)') listItems;

//...
attached(){
    this.listItems.forEach((e) => {
        e.actionHandler = this.actionHandler;
    });
}
```

And everything worked just fine until we started to load data dynamically. In this case `listItems` is empty since the element is initialized before the child elements re-rendered.

#### So, the question is:

How would I make `@children` be re-calculated?

I understand that we could bind the `actionHandler` to all children when we were repeating over them, but this would start to look really ugly when we add some more logic like

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<my-element>` has a dependency on it's parent `<my-list>` element's actionHandler, you can express that declaratively and let Aurelia's dependency injection system do the rest.  Here's a couple of ways to do that...

*If `<my-element>` will always be within a `<my-list>` (doesn't necessarily need to be directly within):*

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@inject(MyList)
export class MyElement {
  constructor(list) {
    this.actionHandler = list.actionHandler;
  }
}
```

*If you need access `<my-element>`'s closest parent custom element, regardless of what it is:*

```js
import {inject, Parent} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@inject(Parent.of(Element))
export class MyElement {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.actionHandler = parent.actionHandler;
  }
}
```

I know this wasn't exactly what you were asking but I'm proposing this in case it's a simpler way to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

The Aurelia Cheat Sheet is telling that:

> @children(selector) - Decorates a property to create an array on your class that has its items automatically synchronized based on a query selector against the element's **immediate** child content.

so i guess it is not possible to use `@children` with dynamic data.

You might should go with the Parent approach, like the previous answer is suggesting.